# Kubernetes undefined noderesources.preFilterState

Tags: go, github, kubernetes, scheduler, go-modules

I am rewriting the logic of Kubernetes' NodeResourcesFit plugin, I want to use `preFilterState` like https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/419e0ec3d2512afd8c1f35a44862f856bc4ac10f/pkg/scheduler/framework/plugins/noderesources/fit.go#L91, so I import it in the code:

`import "k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/scheduler/framework/plugins/noderesources"`

and use it just like:

`s, ok := c.(*noderesources.preFilterState)`

However I get an error: undefined: noderesources.preFilterState

I am not familiar with Kubernetes, so I don't know what is wrong with it. Thanks for your patience.

I try to print `noderesources.Name` but it failed too.

Answer (score 1):

According to the link you're providing, `preFilterState` is not exported and therefore not accessible from the outside of the package.
It has nothing to do with Kubernetes but with go:

- example: https://go.dev/tour/basics/3
- doc: https://go.dev/doc/effective_go#names

I have a feeling you are starting with go, I recommend you play a bit with the fundamentals of the language and maybe use an IDE/Text editor with intellisense to be able to know what you can and cannot call.

Comment: `noderesources.Name` is not the Fit's method but a constant, at <https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/419e0ec3d2512afd8c1f35a44862f856bc4ac10f/pkg/scheduler/framework/plugins/noderesources/fit.go#L42>

Comment: You are right, wen't through the code a bit quick, Fit has a method named `Name` and I did not searched past that.

Comment: @examineLee have you tried running `go mod tidy`, is it giving you any error ? How does your go.mod file looks like ?